# Pass variables from Flask (Python) to Javascript in a Separate JS file via AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, variables, flask

I'm in the learning stages so please bear with me. I've been trying to get answers but often its type="POST" from JS to Flask via AJAX.

This is my app.py.

```py
@app.route("/dashboard", methods=["GET","POST"]);
def dashboard():
    yearCount = #Sample list of dict data
    return render_template("dashboard.html", yearCount=yearCount)
```

(edit) How do I get yearCount from above and pass it to a javascript via AJAX? yearCount will be loaded when dashboard.html renders.

This is my js

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/dashboard',
  type: "GET",
  // data: "How do I get the data yearCount from /dashboard?",
  success: function() {
    alert(this.url);
  }
});
```

I really appreciate the help! Been tearing my hair out figuratively the whole week trying to look for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer of variables during the rendering process from the template:
You can pass the variable on as json with the jinja filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson). If you need the variable outside of your template, you have to pass it as a parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const yearCount = {{ yearCount | tojson }};
      console.log(yearCount);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Loading data while the page is already shown in the browser:
If you want to receive the variable again after the template has been rendered, ajax is the right choice.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/count')
def count():
    yearCount = # your dict data here.
    return jsonify(yearCount)
```

In your example code you are using the [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) library.
However, implementation with the help of the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is also possible. The following is an example of each.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Load the jQuery library. -->
    <script 
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Use the jQuery library to load data with ajax. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // jQuery ajax
      $.ajax({
        url: '/count'
      }).done((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    </script>


    <!-- The fetch api does not require any additional library. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // fetch api
      fetch('/count')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still unclear though. All your codes run through the script tag in html or in a separate javascript file? I ran the $.ajax({
  url: '/count'
}).done((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}); in js but it says "$ is not defined."

Comment: @JamesTan Sorry, I tried to change my answer to make it easier to understand. Should you still have problems, please let me know.